# How to factor $(z^2+1)^5$?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am trying to compute the residues of a function and I need to find the zeros of the commplex polynomial in the denominator which is $(z^2+1)^5$. How can I factor this by hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you factor the difference of two squares, $z^2 + 1$?

Comment: @EricTowers $((z-i)(z+i))^5=(z-i)^5(z+i)^5$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Does this mean the order of the zeros at i and -i is 5?

Comment: @SamKirkiles That is right.